# Correlation between Leaks and Call Tree in Instruments

Tags: ios, instruments

I am using the Leaks instrument for assessing memory leaks in my iOS project. The Leaks console shows 1 leak of 336 bytes and the Call Tree console shows 177 leaks of 11.47 KB. How can they be different? Isn't the call tree supposed to refer to the allocations of leaked memory only?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your question why the Leaks view (screenshot 1) shows one total leak and the Call Tree view (screenshot 2) shows 177 total leaks? If so, update your question to reflect that. The total number of leaks should match in both views.

Comment: Added this query as well.

Comment: Don't just add the question. Your question is why the total number of leaks and total amount of leaked memory are different in the Leaks and Call Tree views. Edit your question to reflect that. Get rid of most of your first paragraph and the last paragraph. They add nothing to what you're asking. Edit your question so you show the screenshots and ask why the Leaks view shows 1 leak of 336 bytes and the Call Tree view shows 177 leaks of 11.47 KB. That's a good question. I would like to know the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input..

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, ask on Apple's paid developer forums. Apple recently revamped their forums. There's a Performance Tools section of the forum under Xcode. You may be lucky enough to have an Apple engineer respond to your question. Apple engineers have the most knowledge of how Instruments works.